# GDAL not summing rasters correctly, multiplying by 2

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, polygon

I have the following two overlapping polygons, displayed in QGIS from a single shapefile:

[image]

I want to create a separate raster for each polygon, with the "Population" value burned in using the following in GDAL from OSGeo4W Shell:

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,2) DO gdal_rasterize -a Vehic_Pop -l Polygons -where "Polygon_ID=%i"  -tr 100 100 Polygons.shp Polygons_Pop%i.tif
```

This creates the 2 following raster files:
a)

[image]

b)
[image]

a) has the value of 595 burned into all non-zero pixels, and b) has the value of 161 burned into all non-zero pixels. And so the black part of each raster = 0.

Now, I want to add a) and b) together into a single output raster. Predicting what this will be, any overlapping areas will see a) and b) added together, the non-zero areas that do not overlap will remain the same, and all areas with no non-zero pixels, will of course, remain 0.

And then I navigate to the folder a) and b) are located in, and use GDAL again to sum these two rasters, located within the same folder using (within OSGeo4W Shell):

```
for %f in (*.tif) do gdal_calc -A %f -B Polygon_Result_Raster.tif --outfile=Polygon_Result_Raster.tif --calc=A+B
```

where `Polygon_Result_Raster.tif` is a blank raster (all 0 pixels).

This is the product:
[image]

But this is not correct, or what I wanted. These values are twice what they should be. The overlapped area should be 756, since 161 + 595 = 756. The overlapped area is incorrectly 1512, but I see this is because all pixel values got multiplied by 2, since 1190 + 322 = 1512.

Why did GDAL do this when I never specified to multiply by 2, and how can I fix this to get the summed raster I am trying to get?

Comment: Have you tried to run commands manually step by step without using `for %f in (*.tif)` and to check what you have in the result raster after each step? Perhaps to loops does not work as you expect. Mayby also `Polygon_Raster.tif` is included in *.tif.

Comment: That was a great suggestion, thanks. I was able to solve the problem. I realized the problem that must have been happening, was that raster a) was added to the blank `Polygon_Result_Raster.tif`, and then raster b) was then added to `Polygon_Result_Raster.tif`, and then since `Polygon_Result_Raster.tif` of course ends in `.tif`, `Polygon_Result_Raster.tif was added to itself, thus telling me why the values were all double. I changed the ends of the names of the polygon rasters to `test.tif`, and thus changed the code to use `*test.tif`, and this solved the problem.

Comment: Also, I realized I missed in my post that the file I was writing over was called `Polygon_Result_Raster.tif` and not `Polygon_Raster.tif`, so I edited my post to fix that.